# Flutter Fexible Widget doesn't resize when keyboard shows

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I am working on app which has a chat screen, So I finished with most of the functionality but I noticed that listView isn't resizing when the keyboard shows but the message input does move up.

[image]

As you can see Input does move up but not the `ListView` so I tried to move the `ListView`to bottom when the keyboard shows up by moving it to bottom using `ScrollController` but it also didn't work

Here's my current implementation:

`chat_view.dart`

```dart
    Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          MessageListView(),
          ChatInputToolbar(),
        ]
      )
    );
```

`message_list_view.dart`

```dart
Flexible(
      child: ListView.builder(
        controller: scrollController,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        reverse: false,
        itemCount: messages.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {}
      )
    );
```

Comment: Replace your `ListView` with 

`SingleChildScrollView` and a `Column` within it

Comment: @Abdulrahman I just wrapped the `Container` in `SingleChildScrollView` and it worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should wrap your container into `SingleChildScrollView`, maybe that will help you. I would write something like this:

```dart
return SingleChildScrollView(
child: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          MessageListView(),
          ChatInputToolbar(),
        ]
      ),)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Scaffold widget at the start of your widget tree, it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In your Scaffold, set resizeToAvoidBottomPadding property to false then try:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
```

Comment: Well doing so will even stop moving the `ChatInputToolbar`.

Comment: `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` is always `true` by default

Comment: use Expanded() class.